# jquery Radio input validation

Tags: jquery

```
    <form id="v-1">
        <input type="radio" name="ot-1" value="o-1" /> answer1
        <input type="radio" name="ot-1" value="o-2" /> answer2
        <input type="radio" name="ot-1" value="o-3" /> answer3
        <input type="radio" name="ot-1" value="o-4" /> answer4
    </form>
```

How to make: if checked Answer 1, then in `var test` adds 1 point, if one of other Answers cheked, then adds 0 points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form id="v-1">
    <input type="radio" name="ot-1" value="o-1" /> answer1
    <input type="radio" name="ot-1" value="o-2" /> answer2
    <input type="radio" name="ot-1" value="o-3" /> answer3
    <input type="radio" name="ot-1" value="o-4" /> answer4
</form>
```

JS:

```
<script>

    test = 0;
    $('input[name=ot-1]').click(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="o-1"){
            test=test+1;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In jquery you can use the following to get the value of a checked radio button

```
var value = $("input[@name=ot-1]:checked").val();
```

U can use this in a button event:

```
$('#submit_button').click(function() {
    var value = $("input[@name=ot-1]:checked").val();
    var test=0;
    if (value == "o-1") {
        test = 1;
    }
});
```